# Binding Dictionary or ExpandoObjects to DataGrid

Tags: wpf, vb.net, dictionary, wpfdatagrid

I am trying to bind `List(Of Dictionary)` to a WPF DataGrid using dictionary keys as columns. So far with limited success.

Here's what I have tried:

The DataGrid:

```
    <DataGrid x:Name="DictDataGrid"  Margin="24,17,144,37" 
              AutoGenerateColumns="False"
              >
    </DataGrid>
```

And here, how I tried to do it with comments

```
    Dim DataList As New List(Of Object)
    Dim MyDict As New Dictionary(Of String, Object)

    ' Creating the first entry and adding it to list
    MyDict = New Dictionary(Of String, Object)
    MyDict.Add("Name", "New Name for this thing")
    MyDict.Add("Info", "Information about this thing")
    DataList.Add(MyDict)

    ' Creating the second entry and adding it to list
    MyDict = New Dictionary(Of String, Object)
    MyDict.Add("Name", "Next thing")
    MyDict.Add("Info", "Information about next thing")
    DataList.Add(MyDict)

    Dim tcol As New DataGridTextColumn

    ' Creating and adding a column and trying to bind it to "Name"
    tcol = New DataGridTextColumn
    tcol.Binding = New Binding("Name")
    tcol.Header = "Name"
    Me.DictDataGrid.Columns.Add(tcol)

    ' Creating and adding a column and trying to bind it to "Info"
    tcol = New DataGridTextColumn
    tcol.Binding = New Binding("Info")
    tcol.Header = "Info"
    Me.DictDataGrid.Columns.Add(tcol)

    ' Trying to assign the created list as data source for the datagrid
    Me.DictDataGrid.ItemsSource = DataList
    End Sub
```

Can someone please help me figure out what is wrong?

The result I'm looking for would be something like this:
[image]

Instead I'm getting empty rows.

EDIT :
After recommendation in comments, I tried to use `List(Of ExpandoObject)` instead of `List(Of Dictionary)`. So I set `AutoGenerateColumns` to `True` and changed my code to this:

```
    Dim TestObj As New Object
    Dim DataList As New List(Of Object)

    TestObj = New ExpandoObject()
    TestObj.Name = "This is the new name"
    TestObj.Info = "This is the new info"
    DataList.Add(TestObj)


    TestObj = New ExpandoObject()
    TestObj.Name = "Second name"
    TestObj.Info = "More info"
    DataList.Add(TestObj)

    Me.DictDataGrid.ItemsSource = DataList
```

Still doesn't work. Do I still need to add columns manually or am I missing something?

Comment: Each entry in `Dictionary` will be one row where item is `KeyValuePair<String, Object>` (in your case) where one column can be bound to `Key` second to `Value` (both read-only). As far as I can see want 2 items per one row. You better create view model class with `Name`, `Info` and potentially other properties and bind to list of that

Comment: @dkozl I need to able to be able to add more properties at runtime. I don't know all the properties I will be needing. Edit: There will be more items per row (more entries in dictionary)

Comment: If you need to have dynamic properties you can try with [`ExpandoObject `](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.dynamic.expandoobject(v=vs.110).aspx) as your item class. You can bind to properties of an object that implements the `IDynamicMetaObjectProvider` interface

Comment: Ok. Thanks for the idea. I will try this. Will post results whether it worked.

Comment: @dkozl I tried using ExpandoObject, but it still does not bind to the DataGrid. I'm still missing something. Added more information in the original post.

Comment: Found my mistake. I still needed to add columns manually. It works now! Thank You for the help!